# Convert BufferedReader to File

Tags: java

I have a servlet which returns a PDF document to the requesting user. When it is called from a browser, the PDF document is automatically downloaded.
Now I need to call this servlet from Java (standalone code, not server side). Once this Java code gets the PDF document, it needs to convert it to images using Apache PDF Box API.

This is how my Java code looks like. It writes bytes to the screen.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Stream/Document&type=pdf");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
String line = in.readLine();
System.out.println( line ); 
in.close();
```

and this is how the code to convert it to Images looks like

```
String pdfFileName = "myfile.pdf";
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFileName));
```

Now I need to combine these two so that the PDF file that is downloaded (in memory, would prefer not to write it to Filesystem) is converted to JPG. So, instead of passing a hardcoded filename, I somehow need to convert the BufferedReader object to File object and pass it as an input to PDDocument.

I am not able to make out how this conversion would happen.

Comment: Hint: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.io.InputStream) (and **InputStream**Reader)

Comment: Your first mistake is that PDF files are not character data and should be read with an `InputStream`, not a `Reader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html), `PDDocument` can also load from a byte array or `InputStream`.

Thus, simply use the input stream from your `url` and pass that to `PDDocument.load(InputStream)`.

Comment: I tried the following 

[code] 
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Stream/Document&type=pdf");
  InputStream in = url.openStream();
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(in);
  document.close();
[/code]

but it gives me the below error

[code]
java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:244)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:973)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:875)
[/code]

Comment: It seems your servlet sends data which is not a PDF. Can you open that PDF with a regular PDF viewer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `load(InputStream input)` (https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) and directly hand `url.openStream()` to that.

*UPDATE:* To consider Tilman Hausherr's comment you could use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
    final URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Stream/Document&type=pdf");
    final PDDocument document;
    try (InputStream urlStream = url.openStream()) {
        document = PDDocument.load(urlStream);
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the stream.